# Prove that $V=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,..):(x_1,2x_2,3x_3,..)\in l_\infty\}$ is linear space

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

We have $V=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,..):(x_1,2x_2,3x_3,..)\in l_\infty\}$. How to prove that is it linear space? I think, that here maybe we can begin from that $V\subset c_0$...

Comment: Show that $V$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Ok and additional question Maybe can you also (by use this info) say is it factor space $l_\infty /V$ a finite-dimensional linear space? or infinite?Why? @suchan

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_n)_n,(y_n)_n\in V$ and $\alpha,\beta\in{\mathbb R}$.

By definition of $V$, $(nx_n)_n$ and $(n(y_n)$ are both bounded, so ther is $M>0$ such that $n|x_n|\le M$ and $n|y_n|\le M$ for all $n\in{\mathbb N}$.

Then $(z_n)_n:=\alpha(x_n)_n+\beta(y_n)_n=(\alpha x_n+\beta y_n)_n$ and let us see that this sequence belongs to $V$.

Indeed, $n|z_n|=n|\alpha x_n+\beta y_n|\le |\alpha| |x_n|+|\beta||y_n|\le M(|\alpha|+|\beta|)$, so the sequence $(nz_n)_n$ is bounded and this means that $(z_n)_n\in V$ as desired.

Comment: Maybe can you also (by use this info) say is it factor space $l_\infty/V$ a finite-dimensional linear space? @TitoEliatron

Comment: Sorry, @EeMm, I don't know.

Comment: No, $\ell_\infty/V$ is not finite-dimensional; convince yourself that the sequences $(n^{-1/k})_n$ for all integers $k\geq 2$, form a linearly independent set of the quotient.